# Conditionally update a huge table having millions of records

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4

I have a huge mysql 2 tables containing over 1 million of data each. Currently I have to merge some columns from one table to the other and then conditionally update the first table.

Here's a sample code to show you what I mean

Currently I'm using Laravel 4.1 to execute the queries. and updating the data at chunks. Unfortunately, if I try to update more than 20 entries in this method, the server crashes.

```
$records = Record::where('MINE_ID','!=','1')->skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
//Equivalent to "SELECT * FROM records LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20"

        foreach ($records as $record) {

                $id = $record->room_id;
                $lat = $record->lat;
                $lng = $record->lng;

                $update = DB::table('accidents')
                            ->where('room_number', $id)
                            ->update(array(
                                'LATITUDE' => $lat,
                                'LONGITUDE' => $lng
                                ));

        }
```

MySQL table engine is innoDB. Is there a faster and easier way to do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION
I have added indexes to all the tables. I heard dropping the indexes help? Also, they are BIGINT. Does it affect performance?

Comment: You're usually better off using a raw SQL query when working with huge datasets.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Gordon... I'm more concerned about the method. The code I pasted works.. But I'm looking for a direct query without the need of apache server or php. Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: None of the information (including the code) is very useful. This is a database question, not a php or laravel question. From your description, it seems that you can probably do all of this with one or two queries which will be very fast. Could you describe the tables involved and tell exactly what you're trying to do with them?

Comment: Sorry that you did not find useful information here. I'm adding as much information possible now

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider of loading the full data into your table as temp table first, then drop  the original one, rename the temp table as your original table's name. It should be easier.